# Having difficulty understanding how to find the maximum volume with cost constraint.

Tags: calculus, optimization, volume

We have 1000USD to buy the materials to build a box whose base length is seven times the base width and has no top. If the material for the sides costs 10USD/cm2 and the material of the bottom costs 15USD/cm2 determine the dimensions of the box that will maximise the enclosed volume.

Question from: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/ProblemsNS/CalcI/Optimization.aspx

I've tried solving it but each time I get a different answer and it doesn't make any sense. I got 164.65cm3 as an answer...

Comment: Call base length $L$, weight $w$ and height $h$. Now set up equations based on what you know and an expression for what you want to maximize.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @mathreadler i did that and I'm pretty sure my following out is right but my answer never makes sense.

Comment: Show us the work you have done, we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Show us your calculations and we'll critique them.

Comment: @saulspatz I posted it in 'answers' but I added a link of how I did it cause idk how to use math formats here

Comment: It's pretty easy to get started using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

*This is more a hint than a full solution! I can only help further if you can show what you are actually stuck on.*

You can setup the problem as mathreadler suggested. Let $L$ be the length of the box, $H$ be the height of the box and $W$ the width of the box. Furthermore we define $c_b$ to be the cost of the bottom per unit area and $c_s$ the cost of the side per unit area.

Now we notice that $L = 7W$. We can now setup equations for the cost and the volume of the box.

The total volume, V, is given by:
$$ V = L \times W \times H = 7W^2H $$

The total cost, C, is given by (where A denotes area):
$$ C = A_{bottom}c_b + A_{side}c_s = 7W^2c_b + (W+7W+W+7W)Hc_s = 7W^2c_b + 16WHc_s$$

The total cost is constrained:
$$ C = 7W^2c_b + 16WHc_s  = 105W^2 + 160WH \leq 1000 $$

You now have to balance the width and hight of the box in such a way that the constraint is met, and the volume is as large as possible. You can do this using derivatives. Hopefully you can now do some sensible calculations

Comment: could you please go through my answer and see where I went wrong? I don't see what I did wrong but the answer doesn't make sense to me... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zcn54omplevwvERg1C8Rf9bT_AxkBHFSFESaM9Yh_TM/edit